# Setting up a default avatar image when a user registers to a social network website

Tags: php, mysql

I needed to know how one would go about setting up a default avatar image for a user upon registration and allow the user to upload one of their own later. Like in facebook.

My user table fields(shortened):

```
user_id, first_name, last_name, username, tel_no etc.
```

My pictures table:

```
Pic_id, pic_large_url, pic_thumb_url, user_id, avatar, timestamp
```

I need to know what kind of php code I need to be able to accomplish this. Do I put my default_avatar.png image in a folder and reference it in the pictures table and where do I go from there?
I wanted to use an avatar (bit) field 1 if it is a user's avatar, 0 if it is not.

I also have an updates table that allows users to upload text and images in their updates or just text only as follows:

avatar pic - update text - update image(if image)

avatar pic - update text - default image(if update image not uploaded)

default avatar pic - update text - default image(if update image not uploaded)

I guessing if i find out how to put a default avatar, ill find out how to do the above.

I will appreciate any help out there.

Comment: A user can have multiple avatars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `avatar` database field, either setup the default to point towards your default avatar, or you can check if its `null`.

If it is null, render the default avatar image :)

Comment: you mean upload a a default pic in a folder with a reference to it in the database. Set the avatar field to 1. When a user registers, I set avatar equal to the picture_id of the avatar image(which is constant)? And when a user removes their own avatar, it sets up the old avatar?

Comment: Yes, you would have a default pic in your directory.  You can either point directly at it in your PHP code, should the database field be empty, or you can setup your database to automatically set it as the default when you add a new user.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same default image for everyone then I wouldn't bother storing it in your database.  Just check if the user has a custom avatar, if so return that url, otherwise return the default path.

```
function displayAvatar($userId) 
{
    $query = getUserInfo($userId) // this is a function that would query the db to get a user's info, or to get info from your pictures table, lets assume it returns an array
    if($query['avatar']===1) {
        return $query['pic_thumb_url'];
    }
    return '/path/to/default/avatar.jpg';
}
```

Then in your html you could do something like this:

```
<div class="avatar"><img src="<?php echo displayAvatar($user); ?>"/></div>
```

I'm assuming here that you have some sort of user object with access to the pictures table.

Comment: Thank you Jeff Busby for your reply. The site Im building creates a session which is equivalent to the user_id after loggin in. Is this what you mean by user object?

Comment: No I was referring to a data class that holds your user's information.  But you could mange this with just the id of the user but you'd have to do the lookup of the user in the displayAvatar class, I'll modify the code to show you what I'm referring to.

Comment: Ok Thanks again Jeff. Much appreciation